# fine the limits :$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin 2x-2x\cos x)(\tan 6x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))}{x\sin x \tan x\sin 2x}=?$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

fine the limits-without-lhopital rule and  Taylor series :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin 2x-2x\cos x)(\tan 6x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))}{x\sin x \tan x\sin 2x}=?$$

i know that :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}$$

But I can not answer please help .

Comment: any thoughts by yourself?

Comment: @Arnaldo .$\tan 6x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))=\tan 6x-\cot(\frac{\pi}{6}-4x)+\cot(\frac{\pi}{6}+2x))$
now ?

Comment: I believe the answer should be approximately 2.33

Comment: If you can solve $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\frac{\sin x}{x})$ (with allowed methods) than I will show you the (elementary) rest. :-)

Comment: @user90369 . how ? please write

Comment: It is described below, what I meant. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know, that $\enspace\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\frac{\sin x}{x})=\frac{1}{3!}\enspace$ then you can answer your question easily:

$\displaystyle \frac{(\sin(2x)-2x\cos x)(\tan(6x)+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))}{x\sin x\tan x\sin(2x)}=$

$\displaystyle =\frac{(\sin(2x)-2x\cos x)(\frac{\sin(6x)}{\cos(6x)}-\frac{\sin(6x)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x)})}{x\sin x\tan x\sin(2x)}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{2\sin x\cos x -2x\cos x}{\sin x\tan x\sin(2x)}6\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}(\frac{1}{\cos(6x)}-\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x)})$

$\displaystyle =-\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\frac{\sin x}{x}) (\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x)^2 \frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}   6\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}(\frac{1}{\cos(6x)}-\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x)})$

$\displaystyle \to -\frac{1}{3!}6(1-4)=3\enspace$ for $\enspace x\to 0$

A note about what I have used:

$\displaystyle \tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

$\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$

$\displaystyle \tan x-\tan y=\frac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos x\cos y}$

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a different way**.

You can use [standard Taylor series expansions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html), as $x \to 0$,  to get $$\sin 2x-2x\cos x=-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4) $$ $$\tan 6x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))=-18x+o(x^2) $$ $$x\sin x \tan x\sin 2x=2x^4+o(x^5)$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin 2x-2x\cos x)(\tan 6x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}-2x)-\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+4x))}{x\sin x \tan x\sin 2x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{18}{3}x^4+o(x^5)}{2x^4+o(x^5)}=3. $$

Comment: but : in here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx+%5Cto+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7B(%5Csin+2x-2x%5Ccos+x)(%5Ctan+6x%2B%5Ctan(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B3%7D-2x)-%5Ctan(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B3%7D%2B4x))%7D%7Bx%5Csin+x+%5Ctan+x%5Csin+2x%7D

Comment: @Almot1960 You are right, I had a typo, now corrected... thanx!